# Sent jQuery var value to Scala Play route function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework-2.0

I have some route and function look likes :

`GET        /item-state/:id        controllers.Application.getState(id:String)`

I use jQuery datatables and i need handle row click. I try do this:

```
$('#statTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   var data = table.row(this).data();
   console.log(data);
   @routes.Application.getState($(data"id"));
} );
});
```

but this way wrong. How can I use jQuery var value in scala function?

Comment: After further research you can do something similar to your original question with a little more code. I am away from computer so will update later. This link should help http://semisafe.com/coding/2015/03/31/play_basics_templates_and_ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly tell what your going for so here are a few options:

### Plain jQuery no Play features

```
$.get('http://localhost:9000/item-state/' + data,function(success){

 //handle logic here.Not sure if you need to append the string id to data but hopefully this makes sense
});
```

### Play's javascript router

Play has two ways to generate a javascript router:

1. Embedded in Scala template with use of * @javascriptRouter* directive
2. In an action where they can be used by your pages

### Helpful links:

[Play docs on JSRouting](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJavascriptRouting)

[Nice tutorial with recent Play version (2.3.4)](http://blog.knoldus.com/2014/10/07/tutorial-ajax-calling-in-play-framework-2-3-4/)

Comment: Haven't seen any activity - do you need any further information?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this easily with the help of AJAX GET call. Whenever the person will select the row, it will generate an ajax get request and which in turn will route to the controller function.

```
var callurl = "/item-state/{id}";

$('#statTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   var data-id = $(document).find('.selected').attr("data-id");
   //now by getting the id of the selected row,pass it to the url.
   callurl = callurl.replace("{id}",data-id);
   $.ajax({
     url:callurl,
     type:GET,
     success:function(data){ //if any data returned from the API,usually a JSON
         do-something;
       }
      error:function(xhr){  //display the error if resource not found or server error on the request
        notify-with-message;
      }
    )};

});
```

**This way you can pass the jquery or any script variable to your route function.**

My company is using play framework for the product's webapp handling and we have been doing these kind of things for quite some time. So, it is a working solution. Further , specify your needs clearly.Any queries, feel free to ask.